# How to show image in table cell in mailer markdown using laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am using laravel 5.7 and developing a newsletter mailer template in blade where blog posts are shown in table. Please see the code:

**Controller to render mailer template in browser:**

```
$posts = [
        [
        'title' => 'Post with tags',
        'slug' => 'post-with-tags',
        'excerpt' => "Post's Short description here",
        'featured_image' => "1545299956.png",
        'campaign_source' => "campaign source",
        'campaign_name' => "campaign name",
        'campaign_medium' => "campaign medium",
        'campaign_term' => "campaign term",
        'campaign_content' => "capaign content",
            ],

        [
        'title' => 'Post with tags',
        'slug' => 'post-with-tags',
        'excerpt' => "Post's Short description",
        'featured_image' => "1545299956.png",
        'campaign_source' => "campaign source",
        'campaign_name' => "campaign name",
        'campaign_medium' => "campaign medium",
        'campaign_term' => "campaign term",
        'campaign_content' => "capaign content",
    ]
    ];


    echo (new App\Mail\EmailNewsletterForBlogPosts("Mailer Short Description", $posts))->render();
```

**EmailNewsletterForBlogPosts:**

```
$email= $this->subject(config('app.name')." : Our newsletter")->markdown('emails.blog_post_newsletter')->with([
            'shortDescription' => $this->shortDescription,
            'posts' => $this->posts
        ]);
```

**blog_post_newsletter.blade.php:**

*This is working*

```
@component('mail::message')

#{{$shortDescription}}

@component('mail::table')
| Image       | Title         |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
@foreach($posts as $post)
| ![Test](http://localhost:8000/storage/blog_featured_images/1545299956.png "THIS IS WORKING")      | Right-Aligned |
@endforeach
@endcomponent



Thanks,<br>
Exchange Support
@endcomponent
```

*but this is NOT working*

```
@component('mail::message')

#{{$shortDescription}}

@component('mail::table')
| Image       | Title         |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
@foreach($posts as $post)
@php
$imagePath = asset('storage/blog_featured_images/');
$imagePath.=$post->featured_image;
@endphp
| ![Test]({{$imagePath}} "THIS IS NOT WORKING")      | Right-Aligned |
@endforeach
@endcomponent



Thanks,<br>
Exchange Support
@endcomponent
```

The problem I guess here is whenever I perform any php operations like concatenating an image name with path, It shows me `null` in browser.
Event I tried passing full image path in `$posts` array but still featured image is not displayed but browser returns `null`.

Please help me guide in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

try below:

```
$imagePath = $message->embed(asset('storage/blog_featured_images/'.$post->featured_image));
```

Comment: Thanks but what is `$message` over here ?

Comment: @DineshSuthar $message variable used for display image.

Comment: @DineshSuthar read https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#inline-attachments

Comment: Nope. I tried this:

`| ![Test]({{$message->embed(asset('storage/blog_featured_images/'.$post->featured_image))}} "THIS IS NOT WORKING")      | Right-Aligned |`

Comment: You mean to say I have to use <table> like html in my mail ? but I tried to `dd` `$message` variable, still no output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185902/discussion-between-dinesh-suthar-and-jinal-somaiya).